# How to load an extenstion of SQLite in SQLFiddle?

Tags: dll, sqlite, sqlfiddle

In SQLite there are some [loadable extensions](https://sqlite.org/loadext.html). How can I load an extension then use it in [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)?

For example I want to load [JSON1 Extension](https://sqlite.org/json1.html) then use it for Json fields.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite fiddles run either in the client browser or with SQL.js. Neither supports extensions at all. It would be necessary to change the SQLFiddle web site to run SQLite on the server.

And then, allowing custom extensions would allow anybody to attack the SQLFiddle web server with the code in such an extension; the administrator would have to decide to compile the extension into the SQLite binary.

Comment: Tnx, For your answer, I hope [@JakeFeasel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/808921/jake-feasel) adds an ability for that issue ;).